# Python logging with {} format using logging.config.dictConfig

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to use the string.format() style with python logging module. I copied some examples from this site and modified it with the the new formatter. I'd like to use logging.config.dictConfig to specify the logging format.
My script is:

```py
import sys, logging, logging.config

DEFAULT_LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '{message}',
            'style': '{' # use string.format()
        },
    },
    'handlers': { 
        'default': { 
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',  # Default is stderr
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '__main__': {  # if __name__ == '__main__'
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
        '': {
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
    }
}

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.config.dictConfig(DEFAULT_LOGGING)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info('Hello, {}', 'log')
    sys.exit(0)
```

But an exception raised:

> --- Logging error --- Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/**init**.py", line 1081, in emit
> msg = self.format(record)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/**init**.py", line 925, in format
> return fmt.format(record)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/**init**.py", line 664, in format
> record.message = record.getMessage()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/**init**.py", line 369, in getMessage
> msg = msg % self.args TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting Call stack:   File "test/dbg/log.py", line
> 48, in 
> logger.info('Hello, {}', 'log') Message: 'Hello, {}' Arguments: ('log',)

For some reason python is trying to format using % formatter (msg = msg % self.args). How can I modify my script to point to the correct formatting? Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
-Uri

Answer (score 1):

One way of addressing this issue is to create a thin adapter around the built-in logging formatter(s).

Example:

```py
import sys, logging, logging.config

class standardFormatterFactory(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, fmt, datefmt, style, validate=False):
        try:
            # 3.x
            super(standardFormatterFactory, self).__init__(fmt=fmt, datefmt=datefmt, style=style, validate=validate)
        except:
            # 2.7
            super(standardFormatterFactory, self).__init__(fmt=fmt, datefmt=datefmt)
        self._usesTime = self._fmt.find('%(asctime)') >= 0 or self._fmt.find('{asctime}') >= 0

    def usesTime(self):
        '''Override logging.Formatter.usesTime()'''
        return self._usesTime

    def format(self, record):
        '''Override logging.Formatter.format()'''
        try:
            return super(standardFormatterFactory, self).format(record=record)
        except TypeError as ex:
            # message contains {} formate specifiers
            record.message = record.msg.format(*record.args)
            if self.usesTime():
                record.asctime = self.formatTime(record, self.datefmt)
            return self._fmt.format(**record.__dict__)

DEFAULT_LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'propagate': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            '()' : standardFormatterFactory,
            'fmt': '{asctime}-{levelname}: {message}',
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
            'style': '{'
        },
    },
    'handlers': { 
        'default': { 
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',  # Default is stderr
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '__main__': {  # if __name__ == '__main__'
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
    }
}

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.config.dictConfig(DEFAULT_LOGGING)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info('Hello, {}', 'log')
    sys.exit(0)
```